# How do I output the results of a HiveQL query to remote server directory?

Tags: hadoop, hive

How do I output the results of a HiveQL query to a remote server directory? 
I know there is a hive command with which we can output results to a local directory, such as:

```
$hive -e 'select * from test' > /home/test/abc.txt
```

Likewise, is there a command or way to do the same but for a remote directory?

Thanks in advance and I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: can you `ssh` to the remote directory?

Answer (score 0):

if you have p**asswordless SSH access** to the remote server then simply scp the output file using:

```
$hive -e 'select * from test' > /home/test/abc.txt | scp /home/test/abc.txt username@remote_hostname:/remote_directory/path
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Aman. Your answer helped me to further enhance and following worked for me                                                                             hive -e 'select * from test' > /tmp/namedpipe |ssh user@abc.com "cat > abc.txt < /tmp/namedpipe